# Problemas en instalación de java 8

Tags: java, java-8, instalacion, macos

Últimamente he estado tratando de programar HIDs con Java 1.8 pues la Library que quiero aplicar solo compila con esta versión.

Lo malo es que cada vez que trato de instalar el JRE 8, no se instala. EL wizard de instalación lo termina exitosamente pero cada vez que busco en el directorio encuentro solo 1.6 y 1.7.

Estoy usando OS X 10.10.5. ¿Cómo puedo completar la instalación?

Comment: Te recomiendo que ejecutes `java -version` para corroborar la versión que tienes instalada de Java. Ahorita no estoy en mi equipo Mac, pero cuando lo tenga te comento más sobre este tema.

Comment: En linux yo normalmente le pongo el comando `where java` y `where javac` para verificar las rutas, no sé si funcionen en osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En OSx Java 8 (JRE y SDK 1.8) es instalado en `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

Si termina el wizard de instalación probablemente no estas buscando en el path adecuado.